# IIS 7.5 FTP disable virtual directories

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

I have setup FTP publishing for a website. The user is a windows account that belongs to no group (I removed from the Users group). Everything good except the user can access virtual directories (The fact they do or don't show up on the listing is irrelevant) and modify files. I want the user to only see/modify his physical root directory and subdirectories.

Also, I'd like to know why this user can modify files, even thought I haven't given him any permissions on any directories (Directory properties, Security Tab).

Comment: This article has everything you need to setup FTP the old-school way:
http://www.robbollons.com/index.php/2010/02/23/ftp-7-5-for-iis7-user-isolation-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Could "Everyone" or "Authenticated Users" or a similar user be granted access on disk?  I agree that there must be some group assigned that this user has access to.